# Combine all paragraphs to make a single paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a requirement, I get many `<p>something</p>` inside `#postrightcolumn`. I would like to combine all paragraphs into single one. Here an example:-

```
<div id="postrightcolumn">
    <p>line 1</p>
    <p>line 2</p>
</div>
```

I would like to turn it:

```
<div id="postrightcolumn">
    <p>line 1 line 2</p>
</div>
```

Here is jQuery I'm using which doesn't help:

```
<script>
    //var cleanDescription = "";
    //$('#postrightcolumn p').each(function () {
    //    var $this = $(this);
    //    cleanDescription += $this.text();
    //    console.log("Paragraph found : " + $this.text());
    //});
    //console.log("Combined Paragraph : " + cleanDescription);

    var cleanDescription = "";
    $('#postrightcolumn p').each(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            cleanDescription += $this.text();
            console.log("Paragraph found : " + $this.text());
        },
        function () {
            console.log("Combined Paragraph : <p>" + cleanDescription + "</p>");
        }
    );
</script>
```

I need to know how to call a function in each single loop ends so that I can display combined paragraph.

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you have commented out? It seems like that would do what you're looking for.

Comment: what's the reasoning? if it's due to spacing can simply remove margins with css so the text appears joined

Comment: @charlietfl true, we still be using JS for this?

Comment: no need for js, simple css rule `#postrightcolumn p{ margin:0; padding:0}`

Comment: @charlietfl i still have two lines ?

Comment: not necessarily, could add `display:inline` also

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/q2ek36cx/

Comment: You have accepted an answer that suggests an alternate CSS solution and you have written that you are using that solution. This shows that your real question was different from what you actually asked. The “CSS solution” does not combine `p` elements at all, it only modifies their rendering.

Comment: Well Jukka then perhaps it was an X-Y problem that worked out OK for OP and they are happy with it. Why all the fuss? It's a few paragraphs on a web page, not an accounting database

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela My requirement was combine <p> not with JS or CSS, I tried my luck with JS which is actually not productive compared with CSS? Do you still think my question is not useful for others in future, downvoted?

Comment: The question is confused, and reading the question, answers, and comments will confuse future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My creative no concatenation solution ...not necessarily the most readable one

```
var $p =$('#postrightcolumn p');
$p.first().html(function(){
    return $p.map(function(){
        return $(this).html() ;
    }).get().join(' ');
}).end().filter(':gt(0)').remove();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oa83mm4j/)**</kbd>

Alternate CSS only solution (maintains same # of `<p>` tags)

```css
#postrightcolumn p{ margin:0; display:inline}
```

<kbd>**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/q2ek36cx/)**</kbd>

Comment: The CSS code is not a solution to the problem posed. It does not combine `p` elements, it only affects their rendering.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I fully understand that, bit intent is not fully known is it? If issue is simply spacing it would accomplish the task with minimal overhead or FOUC

Comment: It is indeed obscure what the intent is, but you should not present something as a *solution* (even alternate one) when it does not actually solve or even address the question actually asked. It could be a comment, but it is misleading to call it a solution.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. I'm using CSS way and its working cool, I tried JS way but this ends up working when I've multiple #postrightcolumn on same page. It was combining all instance of #postrightcolumn.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the HTML of the element to the value of the concatenated paragraph values.

```js
var cleanDescription = "";

$('#postrightcolumn p').each(function () {

  cleanDescription += $(this).text() + " ";
  
});

$('#postrightcolumn').html("<p>"+cleanDescription+"</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="postrightcolumn">
  <p>line 1</p>
  <p>line 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I still see same two <p> inside #postrightcolumn check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k9znjqg5/

Comment: looks like this is close to fix

Comment: the dom shows `<p>line 1 line 2</p>`, what are you saying?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the text from the p elements then you don't need a loop because the [`.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) can be used to get the combined text of multiple elements.

So the following code first gets a reference to all the paragraphs, then sets the text of the first one to the text of all of them, then deletes all but the first:

```
var $paras = $("#postrightcolumn p");
$paras.first().text($paras.text());
$paras.slice(1).remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bapw540b/1/

However, as you can see in that demo, using `.text()` (with or without a loop) strips away any html elements within the paragraphs, so you'd lose any italics or embedded images or whatever. So you may want to use the [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html) instead - which as it happens does *not* return the content of all elements at once so then you need a loop:

```
var $paras = $("#postrightcolumn p"),
    html = "";
$paras.each(function() {
    html += $(this).html();
});
$paras.first().html(html);
$paras.slice(1).remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bapw540b/3/

Comment: will fail on `<br>` or `<span>`'s or `img` in the content of <p>`..made sense to me at first though

Comment: @charlietfl - Yes, it will essentially strip all other elements and just keep the text, but then the original code in the question is using the `.text()` method on each paragraph element so it would do the same thing. And the sample only has paragraphs...

Comment: I also have <h3> inside #postrightcolumn, I just want to pick all <p> and combine.

Comment: OK @AVatsa - the new version of my answer changes the paragraphs without affecting the h3 or other elements. If you use `.text()` you lose elements inside the paras (like `<i>` or `<b>`) but keep their text; if you use `.html()` in a loop you keep elements inside the paras. Both ways shown.

Comment: P.S. You may like to add a space after each (original) paragraph's content: http://jsfiddle.net/bapw540b/4/

Comment: The question is about combining paragraphs, so the code using `.text()` is misguided; it’s not part of what is being asked, just part of a failed attempt. So an answer should present the `.html()` approach only (though it might comment on failed attempts after that).